# db2start fails with error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shared-library, db2, os390

Installed db2 10.5 but installation completes with warning that db2start failed
*while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*.

i have both libstdc++.so.5 and libstdc++.so.6 in my /usr/lib/

```
[root@lnxcm8 adm]# ll /usr/lib | grep libstdc++.so.
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      18 Jun 25 16:56 libstdc++.so.5 -> libstdc++.so.5.0.7
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  824172 Jul  2  2015 libstdc++.so.5.0.7
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      19 Jun 26 16:23 libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.19
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1075592 Aug 31  2016 libstdc++.so.6.0.19
```

Also while installation dn2prereq stated that i need *libstdc++.so.6* so i installed it, and now when it complete its installation it fails with error failed to load libstdc++.so.5.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check architecture. /usr/lib contain 32bit libraries. May be you run 64bit db2?
2. Try run ldconfig as root once. It update library cache. It help me sometimes.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, yes i was running 64 bit and didnot had an entry in /usr/lib64/. downloaded manually and installed. Now its working.